# Bootstrap popover not working on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a bootstrap popover working so:

1. Popover opens on click
2. Popover closes when you click outside the popover
3. Popover has default href for if JS is disabled

Code is:

```
<a class="badge badge-popover"
    data-original-title="title here"
    data-trigger="focus"
    data-placement="right"
    data-content="<p>Content Here</p>" data-html="true"
    href="/help">?</a>

$('.badge-popover').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}).popover();
```

It's working fine across all browsers, but not on the iPad.  Any ideas why?  Where am I going wrong?
Thanks :)

I am using Jquery 1.9.1, bootstrap 2.1.1

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: @Jivings I am using 1.9.1

Comment: try chaining the popover before the click

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, nope, that doesn't seem to work

Comment: [Threw it in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDr3q/) -- this works fine for me on iOS6

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - jsFiddle is on hover for me on FF & Chrome, and not working at all on the Ipad (6.1.2)

Comment: Scratch that, it was a problem with jsFiddle, that code is working fine.  The problem seems to be data-trigger="focus" - any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `hover` event:

This should trigger the Popover on Desktop via `hover` and on mobile/tablet via `click`(touch).

```
<a class="badge badge-popover"
   data-original-title="title here"
   data-placement="right"
   data-trigger="hover"
   data-content="<p>Content Here</p>" data-html="true"
   href="/help">?</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer following code snippet to get it works:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
    //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
    //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    }
 });
});
```

This is the easiest way of detecting clicks on the body and close all the tooltips on the page.

You can check the live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mattdlockyer/C5GBU/2/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered the same problem. Changing `data-trigger="focus"` to `data-trigger="click"` works. Hover also works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing data-trigger="focus" to data-trigger="click" works almost ok, but the problem is that the popover remains open even when you click outside of it and you can close it only if you click on the element, that initiated the popover...